# What advanced security options exist for Neo4j?

Tags: authentication, neo4j, authorization, database-management

Our company is considering Neo4j for a database solution. We're using to Oracle dbs, and have relied upon their built in user authentication management to control who can connect to the db, who has read or write access, and what they are allowed to view in the db.

With Neo4j, most of these security options are missing. While we don't necessarily need to control visibility of nodes and relationships on a per-user level, the lack of multiple user accounts and the inability to control read/write access per account could be a dealbreaker. While application access of Neo4j should be well-contained and secure, we want to allow read-only accounts via the browser client to our developers (at least in our dev and qa environments).

The only solution that's jumped out at us so far has been [GraphAware's Enterprise Security](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/03/29/securing-neo4j-with-graphaware-enterprise.html) offering. I'd like to know if there are any other solutions out there that are compatible with Neo4j 3.0. At the moment we are not considering using the Neo4j REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphAware Enterprise Security is compatible with 3.0 and there are no other solutions as far as we are aware. That said, judging from Github activity, it looks to me like the security mechanisms in Neo4j 3.1 will be enhanced to include multiple users and LDAP integration. We have to wait for 3.1 to be out. GraphAware Enterprise will be compatible with Neo4j 3.1 and use its native security features where possible.

DISCLAIMER: I work at GraphAware.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware 3.1 was going to tackle this, something to look forward to, though your Enterprise Security product sets the bar fairly high.

Answer (score 1):

I did find one other partial solution to this, though it has its own hoops to go through to set up.

With the Enterprise edition, in a clustered environment, a node can be configured to be a read-only slave, and configured with its own login/pass for dev use.